# Problem with regex in Rust but not in Python

Tags: regex, rust

I have the following regex that works in Python but I am struggling to make it work in Rust.

My goal is to rewrite a function I have in Python into Rust. This is my rust

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
use regex::Regex;

fn find_danish_address(text: &str) -> Option<regex::Match<'_>> {
    lazy_static! {
        static ref RE: Regex = Regex::new(r"(?:[A-ZÅÆØ]{1}\w{2,80}\s?) # Street name
        (?:(?:\d{1,4}|\w{0,6}) # House number or other identifier
        (?:,|.|)(?:\s\d{0,5}|) # Optional apartment number
        (?:tv|st|kl|mf|th|sal|) # Optional address unit
        (?:,|.|)\s?){0,4} # Optional separator
        (?:DK-)?\d{4}\s # Postal code
        [A-ZÅÆØ]{1}\w{1,40} # City name
        (?:\s[CNVSKØ]{0,2}|) # Optional county code"
     ).unwrap();
    }
    RE.find(text)
}

fn main() {
    let text: &str = "Jeg bor i Gurrevej 48, 1. tv 2650 Hvidovre";
    
    println!("{:?}", find_danish_address(text))
}
```

In Python I have:

```py
import re
from collections.abc import Iterator

# DK ADDRESSES RE
DK_ADDRESSES_RE = re.compile(r"(?:[A-ZÅÆØ]{1}\w{2,80}\s?)" # Street name
                            r"(?:(?:\d{1,4}|\w{,6})" # House number or other identifier
                            r"(?:,|.|)(?:\s\d{,5}|)" # Optional apartment number
                            r"(?:tv|st|kl|mf|th|sal|)" # Optional address unit
                            r"(?:,|.|)\s?){,4}" # Optional separator
                            r"(?:DK-)?\d{4}\s" # Postal code
                            r"[A-ZÅÆØ]{1}\w{1,40}" # City name
                            r"(?:\s[CNVSKØ]{,2}|)") # Optional county code

def find_danish_address(text: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    text_ = text.strip()
    captured = re.findall(DK_ADDRESSES_RE, text_)

    return (' '.join(add.split()) for add in captured)
```

I am a 4 months old Rustaceans, and most possibly it’s my lack of understanding. Go easy on me.

I get the following traceback

```bash
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.97s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: CompiledTooBig(10485760)', src/main.rs:14:8
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/core/src/panicking.rs:142:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/core/src/result.rs:1785:5
   3: core::result::Result<T,E>::unwrap
             at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/core/src/result.rs:1107:23
   4: <playground::find_danish_address::RE as core::ops::deref::Deref>::deref::__static_ref_initialize
             at ./src/main.rs:6:32
   5: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:248:5
   6: lazy_static::lazy::Lazy<T>::get::{{closure}}
             at ./.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/lazy_static-1.4.0/src/inline_lazy.rs:31:29
   7: std::sync::once::Once::call_once::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/std/src/sync/once.rs:276:41
   8: std::sync::once::Once::call_inner
             at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/std/src/sync/once.rs:434:21
   9: std::sync::once::Once::call_once
             at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/std/src/sync/once.rs:276:9
  10: lazy_static::lazy::Lazy<T>::get
             at ./.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/lazy_static-1.4.0/src/inline_lazy.rs:30:9
  11: <playground::find_danish_address::RE as core::ops::deref::Deref>::deref::__stability
             at ./.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/lazy_static-1.4.0/src/lib.rs:142:21
  12: <playground::find_danish_address::RE as core::ops::deref::Deref>::deref
             at ./.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/lazy_static-1.4.0/src/lib.rs:144:17
  13: playground::find_danish_address
             at ./src/main.rs:16:5
  14: playground::main
             at ./src/main.rs:22:19
  15: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:248:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```

Comment: I'm not sure about Rust syntax, but that Python string contains *no lines breaks or white spaces and no comments.* The Rust string would appear to contain all that…

Comment: I was reading regex documentation: https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/ it appears okay 

Comment: The error message `error: repetition quantifier expects a valid decimal` tells you exactly what's wrong. The Rust regex crate [requires explicit `{0,6}` instead of just `{,6}` for repetitions](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/#repetitions). Once that's fixed you'll encounter the `CompiledTooBig` error though.

Comment: Yes, I got that. I will find my demons. Thank you for trying to help

Comment: In case you don't get it working, I strongly recommend the [`nom`](https://crates.io/crates/nom) parser crate for more complex parsing tasks. Regex simply isn't really intended for these kind of complex tasks.